# Mat-icon display based on condition in for loop

Tags: django, angular, angular-ng-if, mat-icon

I have an angular-django app which makes an aPI call to a third-party application and returns json response. I am looping through the response and displaying the data in a table.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of job_list">
     
      <td style="text-align:center">{{item?.ReleaseName}}</td>
      <td style="text-align:center">{{item?.Source}}</td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><mat-icon *ngIf="Successful" style="color:green;">check circle icon</mat-icon>
                                    <mat-icon *ngIf="Faulted" style="color: red;">error icon</mat-icon> 
                                    <mat-icon *ngIf="Stopped" style="color: grey;">cancel icon</mat-icon>
                                    {{item?.State}}
                                  
                                  
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center">{{item?.StartTime | date:'dd-MM-yyyy         HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
      <td style="text-align:center">{{item?.EndTime | date:'dd-MM-yyyy           HH:mm:ss'}}</td>

     
     </tr>
```

Here, I want to display mat-icon based on {{item?.State}} value. For example if the value is Successful, I want to display the "check circle icon", if it's "Faulted", I want to display "error icon" etc. Is this possible?

Update:
Implemented ngIf but alignment is out of order:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like a decent use case for `ngSwitch`, see https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. You can try `ngSwitch` solution but `ngIf` also works:**

```
<td style="text-align:center">
    <mat-icon *ngIf="item?.State === 'Successful'" style="color:green;">check circle icon</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="item?.State === 'Faulted'" style="color: red;">error icon</mat-icon> 
    <mat-icon *ngIf="item?.State === 'Stopped'" style="color: grey;">cancel icon</mat-icon>
    {{item?.State}}                                                               
</td>
```

**2. Or even make it dinamically with a custom method that returns the
icon:**

.html:

```
<td style="text-align:center">
    <mat-icon [class]="getIconByItemState(item, true)">{{ getIconByItemState(item) }}</mat-icon>
    {{item?.State}}                                                               
</td>
```

.ts:

```
getIconByItemState(item, color: boolean = false): string {
   switch(item?.State) { 
      case 'Successful': { 
         return !color ? 'check circle icon' : 'green-icon'; 
      } 
      case 'Faulted': { 
          return !color ? 'error icon' : 'red-icon'; 
      }
      case 'Stopped': { 
          return !color ? 'cancel icon' : 'grey-icon'; 
      } 
      default: { 
         return 'default icon'; // ? 
      } 
   }
}
```

**1. The best solution (if possible) is to make State variable name equals to icon name:**

```
<td style="text-align:center">
    <mat-icon [class]="item?.State + '-color'">{{ item?.State }}</mat-icon>
    {{item?.State}}                                                               
</td>
```

Comment: lacked to put the css of the classes, but it is basically the icon color only

Comment: Thank you. I implemented ngIf (first method), but there is some issue with the alignment, could it be because we are using many mat-icon tags? I have added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: I need more information, try to use developer tools to discover if some element is between the text and the icon or even if the sizes of icons are differents. But you can try to adjust it with css, giving a class to each icon instead of defining style="color: somecolor" and adding properties of alignment.
Update: actually, i guess it's because you leaving blank space between the icon and state text.

Comment: Hi, I resolved it. It was because I had defined a css class for icons previously and the mat-icons were using the css deisgn of that class.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <td style="text-align:center" [ngSwitch]="item.State">
            <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="Successful" style="color:green;">check circle icon</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="Faulted" style="color: red;">error icon</mat-icon> 
           <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="Stopped" style="color: grey;">cancel icon</mat-icon>
                                                {{item?.State}}
 </td>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick reply. I implemneted ngSwitch and got teh error : core.mjs:10144 NG0303: Can't bind to '*ngSwitchCase' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-icon'.

Comment: It's because is `*ngSwitchCase` and not `**ngSwitchCase`, no?

Comment: *ngSwitchCase is throwing error : error TS2339: Property 'Successful' does not exist on type 'Component'.

Comment: Change to `'Successful'` inside switches and not `Successful`

Comment: Did you mean to use single quote instead of double? I used single-quotes, it throws the same error

Comment: `<mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="'Successful'" style="color:green;">check circle icon</mat-icon>`

Comment: This worked. Thank you!